# Java maximum function recursion

Tags: java, function, loops, recursion, max

I'm new to recursion, can you please tell me why the output of this function is = 3

```
public class Rekursion2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {6,1,2,3,1,100,76};
        System.out.println(maximum(arr,3));
    }
    static int maximum(int[] arr, int i) {
        int max = 0;
        if(i < 0 || i > arr.length) {
            return max;
        }
        if(arr[i] > max) max=arr[i];
        maximum(arr, i-1);
        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the output be 3? The call sets `i = 3` and `max` is purely local to the function frame, so the function just returns the greater of `0` and `a[i]`. The recursive call doesn't do anything since the result isn't used. This is a poor use case for recursion--finding the max should be done iteratively with less overhead and won't blow the call stack. Welcome to SO, BTW!

Comment: Instead of telling you, teaching you to debug your code with a breakpoint set at `int max = 0`, and to step through would let you see the state of all the variables at each point of the execution.  This should make it reasonably obvious why it returns `3`.

Comment: And don't set `max = 0`, that won't work if the maximum in the array is negative.

Comment: actually recursion is doing nothing here (just spending time and memory) since the value of `max` is not changed by subsequent calls of `maximum` - if you remove the statement `maximum(arr, i-1)` you will get the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You execute `maximum` with an index of `3`.

`3` is in the bounds of the array, so the method will not stop at this point.

`arr[3]` is `3`(fourth element) which is bigger that `max`(0), so `max` will be assigned to `3`.

After this, the method is called recursively but it does not change anything(you don't do anything with the return value).

At the end, `max`(3) is returned.

Comment: thanks I get it now, how would you do this with recursion and without using the max function?

Comment: Just put `max=maximum(arr,i-1);` between the 2 `if`s and remove the other call to that method.